# Getting TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable' while coding small program

Tags: python

Hi i have only been coding for a short time and am trying to code a program that counts the vowels in a sentence and then returns that number to the user at the moment i am getting the error:

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable'

```
vowel = "aeiou"
vcount = 0
index = 0

sen = input("Enter sentence (If you enter nothing the program will terminate)\n")
senLen = len(sen)

while senLen > 0:
    sen = sen.lower
    while index < senLen:
        if "test"[index] in vowel:
            vcount = vcount + 1
            index = index + 1
    print("You latest sentance was", sen, "\nIt was", senLen, "Characters long\n", "And had", vcount, "Vowels")
    input("Enter sentence (If you enter nothing the program will terminate)\n")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here:

```
sen = sen.lower
```

You set `sen` not to a lowercase version of the original string, but to the string method that accomplishes this. To actually run the method and return the lowercased string, you need to call it with `()`:

```
sen = sen.lower()
```

Then `sen[index]` will work just as well as your experimental `"test"[index]`.

However, your program will still not work properly. As soon as the inner loop gets to a point where the given character is not a vowel, it stops increasing the index, so it keeps checking that same non-vowel character forever. Unindent that line. Additionally, you save the length of the first sentence and then never update it. Instead, calculate it each time the user enters a sentence. Also, you didn't save a new `sen` in the loop. Finally, you never reset `index` and `vcount`, so that aspect doesn't handle new sentences either.

```
vowel = "aeiou"

sen = input("Enter sentence (If you enter nothing the program will terminate)\n")
senLen = len(sen)

while senLen > 0:
    index = 0
    vcount = 0
    sen = sen.lower()
    while index < senLen:
        if sen[index] in vowel:
            vcount = vcount + 1
        index = index + 1
    print("Your latest sentence was", sen, "\nIt was", senLen, "Characters long\n", "And had", vcount, "Vowels")
    sen = input("Enter sentence (If you enter nothing the program will terminate)\n")
    senLen = len(sen)
```

You could make your code shorter and easier to read by using the `break` statement, the `sum()` function, and multiple `print()` calls:

```
vowel = "aeiou"

while 1:
    sen = input("Enter sentence (If you enter nothing the program will terminate)\n").lower()
    if not sen:
        break
    vcount = sum(c in vowel for c in sen)
    print("Your latest sentence was", sen)
    print("It was", len(sen), "characters long")
    print("And had", vcount, "vowels")
```